# GPU under constant 25-30% load

Tags: 12.10, ati, gpu, catalyst, idle

Currently on a fresh install of 12.10 with Unity and the newest AMD 13.3 beta 3 catalyst driver. But even when on the desktop with no programs open it seems to be idling at 25-30% GPU usage and 47-51°C.

I'm using the command "aticonfig --odgc --odgt" to check for the GPU load and temps.

[image: Screenshot]

Under XFCE and LXDE without compositing the GPU idles at 0-1% so I assume this is a compositing issue? But using 30% of a 7970m while idling is just crazy.

Comment: Have you checked what ps -aux gives in the terminal?

Comment: It shows compiz using 3.8% and 

""/usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none""

using 8.7%. But I did also determine that the GPU usage isn't solid. It sits at 0% for ~5 seconds then sits at~30% for ~5 seconds.